# How to make an algorith which calculates expected and actual time to give a number in the -1 to 1 range?

Tags: algorithms

I'm trying to create an algorithm for time spent on a blog post which gives a number in the -1 to 1 range. Negative numbers will mean that users spent less than expected time on a post, while positive numbers means the opposite.

Now, what I've tried to do so far is to:

Set an expected time (in seconds):

- Expected time = Number of words in the post / Average words per
  second, based on age

The actual time a user spends on an article will be recorded from when a user enters and leaves the page.

However, I'm struggling to find a way to user the Expected Time and Actual Time to get a number in the -1 to 1 range, where a more negative number means that the user spent less time than expected and vice versa.

I know that it's possible to normalize a number in the -1 / 1 range with a formula like this:

- 2 * ( (x − minX) / (maxX − minX) ) - 1

But I don't really understand how to use it in practice to get the result I want. So, how can I use Expected Time and Actual Time to get a value between -1 and 1?

Comment: You just wrote the formula – what are you missing?

Comment: I don't get what I should use as minX and maxX.

Comment: @PurpleButterflies to normalize it linearly between to numbers you need to know the full range in advance, which you don't (because the range could change with every new person). There could be several solutions but they depend on what you wish to convey. If it has to be a linear depiction of where everyone fits in the -1 to 1 range then you'll need to recalculate every time the range changes.